# Set and get document height after dynamic call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a smooth scroll plugin found over here [nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)

The first problem I encountered is that it sets itself to 'static html height'. This didnt work for me as my document is loading items on window load. So I added a script I found like this:

```
    $(window).load(function () {

        function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
$('html').height(getDocHeight());
```

This script allows to change the HTML height even after all the dynamic items are loaded, so now my smooth scroll was working again.

But now I face another problem because Im loading items on the click of a button and thus changing the document again. This time my above script doesn't function, so I put the function in the click event:

```
$(".button").live("click", function(){


        function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
$('html').height(getDocHeight());


});
```

This doesn't seem to work for me. So how can I get and set(change) the document height after the click event?

Comment: The problem comes from you declare function getDocHeight() in nested scope!

Answer (score 1):

Try using .on instead of .live. .live is deprecated, look at the jQuery docs for more information.

Also, there's no need for you to re-add the /function/ inside the .on handler... put that outside the .on code, so you aren't rebuilding a function inside the handler every time!

So, your code would be something like:

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

$("some .element above .button").on("click", ".button", function(){
    // put your click handler in here, to adjust the doc height
    $('html').height(getDocHeight());
});
```

I'm pretty sure there's got to be an easier way to get the document height, straight from jQuery, too, so you might not even need your getDocHeight() function at all. Look at http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the anwser. I cant seem to get it to work, I know that it should (logically). The smooth scrolling has its own call for the plugin like this `$('html').niceScroll();` I think I should combine that somehow with the height function. There is another problem which is that it takes a while before all the items are loaded in the document. So I have to account for this and after the loading proces do the height function and after that make the plugin call.

Comment: ps I only wrote the function inside the handler to make it simple and clear:)

Comment: Ah, okay (about the function)... Just as an aside, however, and this is more of a general comment from the UI/UX side of things, these custom-scroller things have the potential to be hell on usability. At least, on nicescroll's site, the area for catching the scrollbar is exceedingly small. I don't know how you're modifying your scrollbar, but other than for touch interfaces (where they are almost irrelevant), this kind of scrolling adds little to usability, which might be a cost that outweighs the "improved" look when people give up in frustration.

Comment: That actually did cross my mind "is it worth the time?" My design is very bold and this might be yet another fancy thing that would stand out and captivate interest. So Im giving it just one more try after I finish my coffee:)

Comment: In the end, it's up for you to decide how to proceed, but you might try giving the design a "smoke test" with some people unfamiliar with it (preferably people you trust to be honest about it), just to make sure you're not going to throw roadblocks out there for your intended audience. Good luck and have fun with it!